# Passing variables between promise methods in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am trying to set a `variable` within one `promise` method and access it in another, but not having much luck.

I have this code:

```
$.getJSON('some/file/')
.done(function(response) {
    var foo = response;
})
.always(function() {
    // How can I access 'foo' here?
});
```

So how can I access the `foo` variable in other promise methods?

Comment: You'll need to declare `foo` outside of `done()`

Comment: This looks like a very bad idea. `foo` wouldn't be set if the promise failed, so your `always` callback would throw trying to use it. What do you actually want to do, what is your real problem that you need to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about the scope if you declare variable outside `done()` function then you can access it in `always()`

```
var foo;
$.getJSON('some/file/')
.done(function(response) {
    foo = response;
})
.always(function() {
    // How can I access 'foo' here?
    console.log(foo);
});
```

You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) interesting as well. Also remember that always will be executed when ajax fails.

Comment: Make sense, thanks very much. Yep, know about the `always` thing, that's the behaviour I want. :)

Comment: maybe done/fail methods is better approach

Comment: Nope, for the situation I am using the code for I don't want the code within the `always` block to rely on the outcome of the retrieval of the JSON file - it *always* has to be executed.